# How to edit built in code completion or snippets in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Although I searched my problem before, I couldn't find any solution.

I need to find the file in which default/built-in code snippets are, and edit it. Indeed I don't know exactly is it from Python extension or the language server which is currently set to "Pylance" in my setting.

As an example, if want to implement `__call__` in my class, in suggestion pop-up there is no indication that it is a snippet: (btw, I haven't defined any custom snippet)

[image]

After *tab* it changes to:

[image]

Which is obviously not what I want. I have to either import `Any` from `typing` module or manually delete those type hints.

**clarification**:

1. OS: Pop!_OS 21.10 x86_64
2. I've checked `./ms-python.vscode-pylance2022.4.2/dist/typeshedfallback/stubs/whatthepatch/whatthepatch/snippets.pyi` file but it doesn't contain those.
3. Also my `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/python` directory doesn't have `snippets` directory as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10565#issuecomment-703177790)
4. Python extension version : `v2022.4.1`
5. Pylance version : `v2022.4.2`

One possible solution would be to define custom code snippets and set them to be on top in the suggestion list. But I hope I could change the original one.

Comment: This is determined by the IntelliCode extension. Internal modification is not supported for the time being. The easiest way is still to override with custom code snippets. Of course. you could file a issue on github:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT AFAIK IntelliCode is a separate extension and is not automatically installed by Python extension. I don't have that extension installed so I don't think it is from IntelliCode.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is probably to define a custom snippet that overrides the existing snippet for `__call__` following the [VS Code snippets documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)

In this case, open the command palette and locate/type `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`, open `python.json` if it already exists under `Existing Snippets`, otherwise type in `python` and select `New Snippets file for 'Python'...`

In your new snippets file, define a custom snippet for `__call__` that's formatted the way you want, e.g.:

```
{
    "call": {
        "prefix": "__call__",
        "body": ["insert your snippet guts here"],
        "description": "custom __call__ snippet"
    },
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already have this solution in my hand in case I don't figure out how to edit those files. However thanks for the response(+1).

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Might I suggest [this online snippet writer](https://snippet-generator.app)?  Supports multiple editors.  Then you can copy the generated code.  Then (on Mac):  menu `Code, Preferences, User Snippets`.  Create or open `python.json` and paste in what you got.  Definitely has been a huge help getting me up to speed with the special json formatting needed in the snippets files.

Comment: just tested works fine for me too.  about overriding the delivered snippets... keep in mind you would lose your customizations every time vscode updated **anything** in those snippets since this is a monolithic one-per-language format.  unlike say sublime which has one snippet per file.

Comment: This is the answer I see everywhere ... yet, it's not an answer to the question. I just can't believe there's no simple way to actually **change** the default snippets other than overwriting them.

Answer (score 2):

As per JRiggles, but re editing, go to [snippet generator](https://snippet-generator.app)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

“You can hide specific snippets from showing in IntelliSense (completion list) by selecting the Hide from IntelliSense button to the right of snippet items in the Insert Snippet command dropdown.” See: [Can I remove snippets from IntelliSense?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just noticed that there is no such option for Python files. I checked it with `.JS` and `.HTML` and yes it works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not generally a Python user. Sorry this wasn’t more helpful.